# Joomla! 1.5 Category Blog Layout parameters update in database but not when displayed

Tags: joomla, parameters, joomla1.5

I apologize if this is an easy question and I was just googling the wrong keywords. It's been a few years since I've used Joomla! but got handed a site to make some changes to, that someone else originally developed and can't seem to figure out what's going on.  I'm running Joomla! v1.5.26.

I'm trying to add a blog section to the site, so I created a blog section and category and then I created a new "Category Blog Layout" in my menu and set the Columns value to 3:
[image: Category Blog Layout Settings]

However, whenever I view the page, it keeps showing 2 columns. So I went to phpMyAdmin and found the menu in jos_menu and confirmed that the database did in fact get updated:
[image]

So next I opened up /components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog.php and added this to to the top of the PHP file to see what values were being loaded:

```
<?php
print '<pre>';
print_r($this->params);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

Which produced the following results on the front end:

```
     ...
     [num_leading_articles] => 1
     [num_intro_articles] => 4
     [num_columns] => 2
     [num_links] => 4
     ...
```

So for some reason, even though I've set the values to update, and they do in fact update in the database, they are not updating on the front end.  I've tried clearing the cache and all that fun stuff, without much luck. If it was just "num_columns" having an issue I could probably just override that functionality.  However, it appears to be doing the same thing with all of the parameters, not just number of columns.  I'm just using that as an example.

I haven't ruled out the possibility that it's a conflict with some third-party plugin yet, but am trying to see if maybe I'm missing something obvious and someone can point me in the right direction.

**--UPDATE: 12/4/12--**

So it appears to be a conflict with the sh404sef plugin. I'm not exactly sure what the deal is quite yet, but when I disable the plugin it works fine, but it happens again once I re-enable it.  Now to see if I can figure out what's wrong with the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out my own problem.  As I stated above, I discovered the problem was with the sh404sef plugin. Apparently anytime you make changes to the menu layout settings, you have to purge your entire SEF URL list and then rebuild it.  It seems quite strange that we'd have to do that every time, but I guess that was intentional for some reason.  Anyway, it's working now.  I just wanted to make sure I posted a solution for anybody else who may stumble across this.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla! 1.5 while the parameters are being saved the implementation is effected/affected(?) by the template in use at the time.

Check your templates index.php, or if present the override for `com_content`'s Blog layout (usually found in `yourSite/templates/yourtempalte/html/com_content/category/blog.php`

You will probably find the override either doesn't handle the columns or has a bug in it.

Comment: First of all, to answer your question, it's "affected". Affect=verb. Effect=noun. /templates/t/html/com_content/category/blog.php did exist, and that was actually the file I was manipulating above. I didn't mention that above, because I've even tried completely removing all that custom code from my template and just using the core, butit still does it, so unless the previous developer jacked with the Joomla! core, I don't believe that's the problem. As far as index.php is concerned, I've rebuilt the entire file, and I don't see anything in there that is even remotely related to the problem.

Comment: Oh and I failed to mention before, I've manually overridden the num_columns setting in the template, and it works, so I don't think it's an issue with the actual code. For now I'm just gonna hard code the parameters into the template, but I really need to figure out why it's doing this.